# Express: unable to set cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I use the below to set a cookie using express.

```
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.get('/a', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.cookie('aaa', 'bbb');
    res.send('something');
});

app.post('/b', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.cookie('ccc', 'ddd');
    res.send('something');
})
```

I can get cookie when get 'a', but can not when post 'b'